# C++ how to get user input using an expression?

Tags: c++, input, io

Obviously this is not a question about how to use `cin`, `scanf` or `getline`.

All of these methods of getting user inputs do not return something, they mutate a variable.

What I want to do is to gave a way to get input and return it so the input getting can be embedded into an expression.

I'm sorry if I'm not explaining this very well. But for example in Python you have the function `input()` which takes one line of text from stdin and returns it as a string so you could do:

```
print( int(input()) + 5 )
```

This takes the user input, returns it, then it is parsed into an int directly and processed, without the need for an extra variable. I want something of this sort in C++ too.

Obviously I can create a function that does this, but I am asking about any way to do this using only the standard library.

Comment: C and C++ have entirely different solutions here. Which one do you want?

Comment: What's wrong with writing a function to do it?

Comment: There are two such functions in C++, `getc` and `fgetc`. They are designed to read `char` input. There are no other standard functions that behave this way. It is a good little exercise to figure out why.

Comment: @tadman Umm... both please?

Comment: @JesperJuhl nothing, I was simply asking about a way to do it with only the standard library because it is possible in other languages and I was curious if it is possible in C++ too :)

Comment: C++ is not Python. One could certainly write the code that implements a function that takes `std::cin`, performs a formatted extraction on it, and returns the resulting `int` value, so you can write `std::cout << i_would_like_an_int_please(std::cin) + 5 << std::endl;`. Nothing stops you from doing this, but you will have to do it yourself.

Comment: Oh and also `getchar`, sorry. Three of them.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks! Not exactly what I wanted but close. I thought a bit about the why part. What came to mind is that obviously you cant return a character array, a `char[]` or `char*` as it would get deallocated but why not return a `std::string` or something similar?

Comment: @Rares Dima - Stackoverflow is not a forum for general discussion like that. It's a question/answer site for *specific* problems. Your question would fit better if you had actually *tried* to solve the problem and then asked about the *specific* problem you encountered with your code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I did try and I have said so in the first line of my question. Research and my own knowledge of C++ led to the  more traditional ways of getting input that I have mentioned in my question. I have a very specific question and I have done my best to make it clear about the specific case I would like information about. What part of my question did you not consider specific? I would be happy to make edits.

Comment: @Rares Dima - Why is writing a function to read the input and return it not acceptable? The standard library does not provide what you seem to want, so you have to do some leg work yourself.  Note: I didn't downvote your question (quite the opposite actually), I just posted a comment. I would have liked to see a [mcve] of what you had tried so far and an explanation of why that is not good enough, is all. 

Comment: @JesperJuhl acceptable or not is not the question here. Obviously you *can* write a function like that yourself or just stick to what the standard library offers and everything will be okay, but as I have answered to someone above when they asked the exact same question: I was simply asking about a way to do it with only the standard library because it is possible in other languages and I was curious if it is possible in C++ too because it is one of the languages I like quite a lot and I would like to know more about it :) This is purely an educational question about a specific functionality.

Comment: If the Standard Library does not provide the specific functionality you want, which it doesn't in this case, then the usual procedure is to *write a function*. Please consult [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) whenever you have questions like this as all the options you have are listed there exhaustively. Any time you're working on non-trivial code you'll probably need to check the documentation as many functions have subtle caveats and limitations that you must keep in mind when using them.

Comment: Oh and of course I forgot `std::istream::get`. Another one to read a `char`, not inherited from C this time. That makes 4. You probably want to read their documentation *carefully*.

Comment: @tadman This question is not about a *procedure*, but about a *design*. It is blindingly obvious what to do if one wants such a function. The fact that the standard library doesn't provide one, despite its apparent usefulness, suggest that it may not be such a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is hardly onerous.  What's wrong with something like this (if you like classic C api's)?  Declare it inline if you want to put it in a header file:

```
int get_int ()
{
    char buf [80];
    fgets (buf, sizeof (buf), stdin);
    return atoi (buf);
}
```

You can do something similar using C++ api's (exercise for the reader).